# AngularJS input type number with string model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I am getting an error message due to an input field I have. It is of type "number" but the actual model is a string. Reason behind this is, that my ngModel value is used in other parts of the application.

However for just one Input Field I need to restrict this as only using numbers.

What is the easiest way to achieve this, without changing the type of ngModel.

Comment: I would create custom directive that works with numbers but doesn't change `ngModel`

Comment: You could cast the string to a number if and when it is for a number type input

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular? I mean, revise the naming and tags in your question accordingly based on what framework you are using :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you can transform string to number:

```
$scope.age = parseInt(ageString);
```

At the HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="age" ng-model="age"/>
```